# Remove the Chapter Number from Section and Subsection Numbering

Tags: formatting, titlesec

I'm trying to number each paragraph of a document, using section and subsection, but it continues to put in the chapter numbers as well...which is not what I want.

Here's the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.5cm}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}[\quad]

\title{Contract Doc}
\date{May 2020}

\begin{document}

   \part{Introduction}
    \setcounter{chapter}{4}
     \chapter{Liabilities}

     \setcounter{section}{1}
     The section number is: \thesection (Chapter.Section)
        %\section{Test}
       \subsection{}I want something like this, but with the "Chapter" number removed; kind of like "chapter a verse" in a Bible, but it's actually section and subsection in this doc.

       \noindent\normalfont\textbf{1.2}~~~More like this...followed by:

       \noindent\normalfont\textbf{1.3}~~~etc.

       \setcounter{section}{2}
       Then the next Bible-like 'chapter' (section really) would look like:

       \noindent\normalfont\textbf{2.1}~~~Blah blah. Even though it's still Chapter 5, Liabilities.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not let LaTeX do the number setting for you? The `\chapter` macro sets the section number to zero and a `\section` increments the section number which sets the subsection number to zero.

The following is a revised version of your solution MWE.

```
% secnumprob.tex  SE 543955
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5cm}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}[\quad]

\title{Contract Doc}
\date{May 2020}

\newcommand{\anonsec}{\refstepcounter{section}} % increment the section number

\begin{document}

   \part{Introduction}
    \setcounter{chapter}{4}
     \chapter{Liabilities}

%     \setcounter{section}{1}
\anonsec % increment the section number and set subsection number to zero
     The section number is: \thesection (Chapter.Section)
        %\section{Test}
       \subsection{}I want something like this, but with the "Chapter" number removed; kind of like "chapter a verse" in a Bible, but it's actually section and subsection in this doc.

       \subsection{}More like this...followed by:

       \subsection{}etc.

%       \setcounter{section}{2} % Set "Chapter" counter
\anonsec % increment section counter and set subsection to zero
%       \setcounter{subsection}{0} % Reset "Verse" counter
       Then the next Bible-like 'chapter' (section really) would look like:

       \subsection{}Blah blah. Even though it's still Chapter 5, Liabilities.

\end{document}
```

Of course, if you really like manually manipulating section and subsection numbers, then ignore the above.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. It is a good one. But I've also made a macro for the number setting, with an addition of the number, and that's it. I actually like mine better. It makes editing the tex file easier, where I can identify the chapters. (I can search for the specific chapter.

Comment: I see you've since figured out a solution, but I would like to second Peter's suggestion about letting tex take care of the numbering. Even if you do manage not to make any mistakes during your "hardcoding", it will make life more difficult for anyone who has to work with your files in the future. If you need a way to easily identify the sections, perhaps you could tweak your macro to instead amend the label name or to leave a comment saying which section you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the answer:

add:

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

to the preamble, and then set each section number to represent the 'chapter' with, for example:

```
\setcounter{section}{2} %just  before the first \subsection
```

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5cm}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}[\quad]

\title{Contract Doc}
\date{May 2020}

\begin{document}

   \part{Introduction}
    \setcounter{chapter}{4}
     \chapter{Liabilities}

     \setcounter{section}{1}
     The section number is: \thesection (Chapter.Section)
        %\section{Test}
       \subsection{}I want something like this, but with the "Chapter" number removed; kind of like "chapter a verse" in a Bible, but it's actually section and subsection in this doc.

       \subsection{}More like this...followed by:

       \subsection{}etc.

       \setcounter{section}{2} % Set "Chapter" counter
       \setcounter{subsection}{0} % Reset "Verse" counter
       Then the next Bible-like 'chapter' (section really) would look like:

       \subsection{}Blah blah. Even though it's still Chapter 5, Liabilities.

\end{document}
```

Cheers!